# How is an empty set a hereditary set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I read the definition of a hereditary, It states that " Hereditary set (or pure set) is a set whose elements are all hereditary sets. That is, all elements of the set are themselves sets, as are all elements of the elements, and so on. "

If I look at the empty set, there isn't an element that in there that's a set because it's empty. How does this satisfy the definition of a hereditary set?

Comment: The empty set is a hereditary set precisely because there are no elements of the empty set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every element of the empty set is a hereditary set. Every element of the empty set is *also* an elephant. When we universally quantify over the emptyset ("$\forall x\in\emptyset(...)$"), we wind up with a true statement for silly reasons ("**vacuous truth**"); dually, if we existentially quantify over the emptyset ("$\exists x\in\emptyset(...)$") we get a false statement for silly reasons.

The definition of hereditary set isn't *positive*, it's *negative*: a set is hereditary if and only if it **doesn't** contain something it **shouldn't**, and the emptyset - containing nothing at all - is therefore hereditary.

Answer (score 1):

Since the empty set has no elements, each element in the empty set satisfies the condition.

Even more is true, each element in the empty set is a pink unicorn!